# List comprehension : is there a concise way to refer to the initial expression in the if condition?

Tags: python, syntax, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a pretty simple list comprehension of the form

```
[initial-expression for name in collection if condition(initial-expression)]
```

But I am facing a case where intial expression is embedding some 'advanced' logic I do not want to duplicate in the if condition.

### Verbose solution

At this point, I wrote :

```
[alias for alias in [initial-expression for name in collection]
 if condition(alias)]
```

Since the initial expression (in the outermost list comprehension) is the identity, it seems overkill.

**Is there a common way to refer to an initial expression in the if condition using some symbolic name ?**

Comment: @Denis: replace `initial-expression` with an arbitrarily long expression. Mine ain't better than any other ;)

Comment: is initial-expression separate function or what?

Comment: @Denis: In my case it is a function for which some arguments are an expression using name as one of the operands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, it's called `filter` and `map` :)

```
filter(condition, map(lambda name: initial-expression, collection))
```

Comment: I am still curious to know if there is a way to actually do it with the list comprehension (which was more of the question).
+1 anyway, I would not be honest if I said I thought about this solution which is for sure less verbose (and took the extra care to be expressed with the symbols used in the question).

Comment: There is no way to create an alias for the initial-expression in a way you expressed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, you should go with your "verbose" solution. There is one improvement I would make for the sake of code clarity and efficiency.

Change:

```
mylist = [alias for 
          alias in [initial_expression for
                    name in collection]
          if condition(alias)]
```

to

```
aliases = (initial_expression for name in collection)
mylist = [alias for alias in aliases if condition(alias)]
```

or

```
aliases = (initial_expression for name in collection)
mylist = list(filter(condition, aliases))
```

Comment: Clarity yes, but efficiency not that much. If you time it 1. is actually 5% faster then 2. and around 5% slower then 3.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez: I should clarify. 2 is more space-efficient than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially create aliasing in a list comprehension by adding a generator that iterates over a single-element collection. Like so:

```
[alias for name in collection for alias in [initial-expression] if condition(alias)]
```

It's not any less verbose than your example, but it's basically equivalent to what you'd get if python allowed something like `let alias = initial-expression` in a list comprehension; it doesn't change the structure of the list comprehension the way your example does.